# Отслеживание нажатия клавиш в фоне

Tags: java, winapi, jni

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Как отследить нажатие клавиши в фоне. Знаю, что можно как-то сделать через JNI, JNA, Winapi. Хотел бы увидеть примеры, как отслеживать нажатие определенной клавиши, когда программа свернута.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Есть [библиотека jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook#about).

Вот зависимость мавен:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
    <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

А [здесь](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage) примеры использования от разработчика. Процитирую код от туда касаемый перехвата событий с клавиатуры:

Global Keyboard Listener

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_ESCAPE) {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

Кроме событий клавиатуры, библиотека умеет отрабатывать события мыши.